# HttpClient and HttpCore jar files not seen by Netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

java 7, NetBeans 7,  Several years of experience with Netbeans and Java.

I'm trying to include Apache's HttpClient (4.3.5) and HttpCore (4.3.2) jar files in my project.  I've added them in both runtime and compiletime libraries.  When I type in the import statement, NetBeans marks them as an error - "package org.apache.http does not exist".  However I can compile cleanly.  Yet when I run the project, first it says "one or more projects are compiled with errors". When I tell it to run, the current code line stops on the first import and says - "Uncompilable source code - package org.apache.http does not exist"

Why oh why oh why does NetBeans not see these two jar files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Netbeans where your libraries are. There are several ways to do that.

**Method 1**

Add HttpClient and HttpCore as a Libraries
  Tools>Libraries

[image]

Name your library

[image]

Browse and select jar files (your HttpClient and HttpCore)

[image]

After that Select your project > Properties > Libraries > select your library

**Method 2 (Easy one)**

Select your project > Properties > Add Jar Folder > select your jar libraries

[image]

Comment: Both of these jar files have successfully been placed in the Libraries section of the project ... in both 'Compile' and 'Run'.  All of the other jar files in the library are properly recognized, just not these two.

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the right **jar** files. Try to re-download the library from **[here](http://apache.claz.org//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.3.5-bin.zip)** and try importing the library again.

Comment: Redownloaded from 'https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi'. Not quite sure what site 'claz.org' is, but I don't trust it. Anyway, no change whatsoever.  And, yes, I selected .jar files.

Comment: **claz.org is just a random mirror which host apache libraries!** LOL!

go through the stacktrace you can definitely find a clue about what cause the error. If not please post the stacktrace here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't download my files from random mirrors.

Comment: If you got your project working please post how you solved it. That may be helpful for someone!